# Typescript - Querying or flattening nested array but keeping some objects as nested ones

Tags: arrays, typescript

Again I'm stuck with a nested Array of objects. I want to flatten it out, but I do have to keep some nested objects. The Problem I'm running into: How to rename the keys of the nested objects since I have an undefined number of nested objects. There might be 3 of them oder 8. So property1_3 has to be renamed to eg property1_3_1, property1_3_2 - depending on how many objects are in the original json data. And how to aply them to the correct parent object.

The json data I recieve looks like:

```
data = [{
    "property1_1": "value1_1",
    "property1_2": "value1_2",
    "property1_3": [
      [{
        "subproperty1_1_1": "subvalue1_1_1",
        "subproperty1_1_2": "subvalue1_1_2"
      }],
      [{
        "subproperty1_2_1": "subvalue1_2_1",
        "subproperty1_2_2": "subvalue1_2_2"
      }]
    ]
  },
  {
    "property2_1": "value2_1",
    "property2_2": "value2_2",
    "property2_3": [
      [{
        "subproperty2_1_1": "subvalue2_2_1",
        "subproperty2_1_2": "subvalue2_2_2"
      }],
      [{
        "subproperty2_2_1": "subvalue2_2_1",
        "subproperty2_2_2": "subvalue2_2_2"
      }],
      [{
        "subproperty2_3_1": "subvalue2_2_1",
        "subproperty2_3_2": "subvalue2_2_2"
      }]
    ]
  }
]
```

What I want to achieve now is:

```
data = [
{
    "property1_1": "value1_1",
    "property1_2": "value1_2",
    "property1_3_index1": {"subproperty1_1_1":"subvalue1_1_1", "subproperty1_1_2":"subvalue1_1_2"},
    "property1_3_index2": {"subproperty1_2_1":"subvalue1_2_1", "subproperty1_2_2":"subvalue1_2_2"}
},
{
    "property2_1": "value2_1",
    "property2_2": "value2_2",
    "property2_3_index1": {"subproperty2_1_1":"subvalue2_2_1", "subproperty2_1_2":"subvalue2_2_2"},
    "property2_3_index2": {"subproperty2_2_1":"subvalue2_2_1", "subproperty2_2_2":"subvalue2_2_2"},
    "property2_3_index3": {"subproperty2_3_1":"subvalue2_2_1", "subproperty2_3_2":"subvalue2_2_2"}
  }
]
```

My last try was:

```
transformData(input) {
  const testArray = [];
  input.map(obj => {
    for (const prop in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && Array.isArray(obj[prop])) {
          for (const [index, element] of obj[prop].entries()) {
            testArray.push(element[0]);
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

but this only leeds to an array with all the single subobjects in one array. I'm also not quite sure if it's best trying to convert the original data or to build a new array as I tried before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to achieve this.

```
transformData(input) {
  return input.map(obj => {
    for (const prop in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && Array.isArray(obj[prop])) {
        for (let i = 0; i < obj[prop].length; i++) {
          const name = prop + (i + 1).toString();
          obj[name] = obj[prop].flat(1)[i];
        }
         delete obj[prop];
      }
    }
    return obj;
  });
}
```